# Selenium TestNG - java.lang.NullPointerException in automation testing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium, android-automation

I am trying to test the login function to my android app. But it displays an exception error `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Code as follows:

```
package tests;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Amazon

{

    public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @BeforeTest

    public void launch() throws IOException

    {

        // Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Bright Roots (Galaxy S4)");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "4d00b778d48a421b"); // Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.1");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.babilok");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.example.babilok.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        try {

            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> Driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),
                    caps);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Test

    public void print() throws Exception

    {

        // locate the Text on the calculator by using By.index()
        MobileElement driver = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='7']")
        driver.click();

    }

//  @AfterTest
//
//  public void close() throws IOException
//
//  {
//      driver.quit();
//
//  }

}
```

Error:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0 Oct 19, 2019 3:48:46 PM
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0 INFO:
>   Detected dialect: W3C FAILED: print java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   tests.Amazon.print(Amazon.java:58)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: I don't really know Java that much, but let's see if this will be helpful. Are you sure this line `MobileElement driver = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='7']")` is correct? Is `driver` different from `NULL` here? You're also creating an object `Driver`, shouldn't you use this one? I mean Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: Can you please format the code and the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the test you use a property `driver` which has not been instantiated, because you create the driver into local a variable called **D**river. See the case-difference? The class property driver has a default value of NULL and that is why you get a nullpointer exception when you try to use it. You cannot use objects that are NULL.

This is a foundational Java programming language issue, I suggest you first learn the programming language before you start automating tests in it. [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486) helped me a lot to understand Java and how to use its classes and standard libraries better. I really suggest you learn how to use Java and its basic OO-concepts first before you continue with your trail and error.

Code change I think might make your example work. This code:

```
       AppiumDriver<MobileElement> Driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),
                caps);
```

Should be:

```
       driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),
                caps);
```

Because you want to use the class variable `driver` and not create a new local variable Driver.

This code:

```
    MobileElement driver = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='7']")
    driver.click();
```

Should be:

```
    MobileElement element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='7']")
    element.click();
```

You cannot re-assing the driver, you want a new variable to interact with elements.

Comment: Hi, can you please check this issues:  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/42855/41592